# How to stop downloading when the client cancels the request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios

In the nodeJs application, I'm downloading a file with Axios. when the client cancels the request I have to stop downloading. After starting downloading How can I stop downloading?

with the following code, I notice that the client cancel its request:

```
   req.on('close', function (err){
    // Here I want to stop downloading 
   });
```

complete code :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Axios = require('axios')


app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

   req.on('close', function (err){
    // Here I want to stop downloading 
   });

    downloadFile(res)
})

async function downloadFile(res) {
    const url = 'https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/161/original/Volume2.mp4'

    console.log('Connecting …')
    const { data, headers } = await Axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })


    const totalLength = headers['content-length']
    let offset = 0

    res.set({
        "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="filename.mp4"',
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": totalLength,
        // "Range": `bytes=${offset}` // my problem is here ....
    });

    data.on('data', (chunk) => {
        res.write(chunk)
    })

    data.on('close', function () {
        res.end('success')
    })

    data.on('error', function () {
        res.send('something went wrong ....')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Axios [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation/) has a section about cancelation.

The code would look like:

```
// before sending the request
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

// then pass-in the token with request config object
axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
});

// upon cancelation
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user');
```

Moreover, looks like there's an open issue for supporting AbortController/AbortSignal in Node.js 15+. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3506).